# Generics to consolidate NSLayoutAnchor

Tags: swift, generics, nslayoutanchor

I want to consolidate the `NSLayoutDimension` `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` and `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` to create a wrapper for my anchors to avoid a long list of convenience methods

The ideal syntax I was looking for was

```
extension UIView {

    func example() {
        attach("width" to:view, "height")
    }

    func attach(_ value:String to view:UIView, _ otherValue:String) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

         let firstAnchor = anchor(for:value)
         let secondAnchor = anchor(for:otherValue)

         return firstAnchor.match(view.secondAnchor)
    }

    // My original expectation for generics

    func anchor<A: NSLayoutAnchor<AnyObject>>(for string:String) -> A {

        switch string {
        case "height":
            return heightAnchor
        default:
            return widthAnchor
        }
        // etc....
    }

    extension NSLayoutAnchor {
        func match(_ anchor:NSLayoutAnchor) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

            return constraint(equalTo: view.anchor)        
        }
    }
```

The closest I seem to be able to get to is...

```
func equivalent(_ dimension: NSLayoutDimension) -> NSLayoutDimension {

    switch dimension {
    case heightAnchor:
        return heightAnchor
    default:
        return widthAnchor
    }
}
```

But here is where I'm getting a bit lost... this isn't really achieving much... ideally I'd want to fetch all of the Anchors in one place i.e. expand `equivalent` so that I can easily access anchors based on the same query..

this is possible with `NSLayoutAttribute`

```
func attribute(for string:String) -> NSLayoutAttribute {

    switch string {
    case "left":
        return .left
    case "right":
        return .right
```

however it doesn't work with the generics as I have them above... I know the syntax is wrong and that anchors are properties on the `UIView`s but I'm not sure how to fix it...

Thanks for your time